# Proving the reciprocal rule by using the difference quotient

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I can't seem to be able to figure this out.

Can someone please help me prove that $f'(x)= -\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $f(x)=\frac1x$ using only the difference quotient and not the reciprocal rule.

Comment: First off, the derivative is $-1/x^2$ not $-x/x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

From simple algebra, the difference between $f(x+h)$ and $f(x)$ is

$1/{(x+h)}-1/x=$
$-h/{(x(x+h))}$

And you work from there.